# Why rust can't find a function in a submodule?

Tags: module, rust

I'm trying to call a function from a module located in a separate file, the function is public and I am calling it using a full path, but rustc still complains about "unresolved name".

### a.rs

```
pub mod b;
fn main() {
  b::f()
}
```

### b.rs

```
pub mod b {
    pub fn f(){
        println!("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

### compilation

```
$ rustc a.rs
a.rs:3:5: 3:9 error: unresolved name `b::f`.
```

When I move the module to the crate's main file, everything works fine.

### one_file.rs

```
pub mod b {
    pub fn f(){
        println!("Hello World!");
    }
}
fn main() {
    b::f()
}
```

Aren't these two ways supposed to be equivalent?
Am I doing something wrong, or it's a bug in rustc?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you have separate files, they are automatically considered as separate modules.

Thus, you can do :

**othermod.rs**

```
pub fn foo() {
}

pub mod submod {
    pub fn subfoo() {
    }
}
```

**main.rs**

```
mod othermod;

fn main ()  {
    othermod::foo();
    othermod::submod::subfoo();
}
```

Note that if you use sub-directories, the file **mod.rs** is special and will be considered as the root of your module :

**directory/file.rs**

```
pub fn filebar() {
}
```

**directory/mod.rs**

```
pub mod file;

pub fn bar() {
}
```

**main.rs**

```
mod directory;

fn main() {
    directory::bar();
    directory::file::filebar();
}
```